# Spring batch admin sample web app with command line arguments

Tags: jboss, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I am trying to monitor the Spring Batch using Batch Admin Mbeans, by either jconsole or 'JBoss operations network'. 
The sample application 'spring-batch-admin-sample-1.2.1.RELEASE.war' is deployed in Jboss EAP6. 
But I don't know how to start the sample application with the usual command line options to expose the MBeanServer, as mentioned in reference doc' http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch-a...rence/jmx.html ' .

JBoss EAP 6 does not declare com.sun.management.jmxremote system properties by default, and according to the issue below, I can't start JBoss with com.sun.management.jmxremote properties in my standalone.conf file
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-1859

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I get around with it by the following,

The Mbeans are enabled in spring batch admin according to [spring batch admin doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch-admin/reference/jmx.html). So after deploying the 'spring-batch-admin-sample-1.2.1.RELEASE.war' in JBoss, we can get the details of MBeans as mentioned in [here](http://simplesassim.wordpress.com/2013/02/06/how-to-list-all-mbeans-in-jboss-as-7-with-jmx-remoting/)

And now i have extended the RHQ's generic JMX plugin to discover and list the spring batch admin metrics.